# VB.NET connection must be valid and open ERROR

Tags: .net, connection

I'm trying to connect a MySQL database to my VB.NET application. Just a login form.

I'm a beginner. So I'm testing with a new project.

When I click the Login button, it says "Connection must be valid and open!"

But the Connection Check button (Button1) is working.

I don't know why...

Here is the source code. How can I fix it?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim Mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        Mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=-------;database=user"

        Try
            Mysqlconn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful.")
            Mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Mysqlconn.Dispose()

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginbtn.Click
        Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        Mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=password;database=user"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            Mysqlconn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from user.Useridpw where UserID='" & Username.Text & "' and UserPW='" & Password.Text & "' "
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("ID PW OK")
            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("ID/PW Duplicated.")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ID/PW Incorrect.")

            End If

            Mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Mysqlconn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems

1. Have not associated the query with command
2. Have not associated the command with the connection

Connection is a property of the command and much be assigned
[DbCommand.Connection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.connection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If this answers your question then you can indicate so by clicking the check